# Deploy website from local machine to webserver

Tags: git, ftp, file-transfer, webserver, windows-server-2019

I want to copy my website to the webserver. These files should be transferred from my local computer to my Windows server. I am running `Windows 10 version 1709 (build 16229.431)` on my local machine and `Windows Server 2019 version 1809 (build 17763.348)` on my webserver. Both machines have a static IP. On both machines `GIT version 2.15.1.windows.2` on the local machine and `GIT 2.23.0.windows.1` on the web server.

So far, I have been copying the files (`Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+V`) via Remote Desktop to the Windows Server. Is there a way to solve this using a PowerShell command or similar? Or somehow with GIT?

I have tried WinSCP, but that didn't work because I couldn't get to the web server. I don't think the solution of copying via RDP is smart.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to use WinSCP?

Comment: I could not connect to the server with Winscp.

Comment: This is the exact error: "Network error: Time limit for connection "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx" was reached."

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't set up or test an FTP server on your webserver.  You'll need to do that to get FTP working.  I use FileZilla for server and client, and it's relatively straightforward.  There might be a way to use http, but that's a lot more complicated than install Filezilla, make a user, connect with that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it. I can now always get the correct version from the repository via GIT. The problem was that the Windows firewall did not allow access from my GIT server. Now I released the web server on the GIT server for incoming and outgoing connections. Now it works. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.